# Get real time data from SerialPort in C# .Net

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am plotting a label text from a serialport. How to get data from serialport without press the button?

this is my code

```js
public string Read()
        {
            try
            {
                this.DataReceived = oSerialPort.ReadLine().ToString();
                return (this.DataReceived);
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Failed";
            }
        } 
        
private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            string x = Read();
            Label1.Text = x;
        }
```

Comment: _"Get real time data..."_ - by not using `Thread.Sleep()` would be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SerialPort.DataReceived` Event for reading the data from serial port. Refer [this msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.